# Why Math Jax rendering on Chrome, but Firefox?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

ale and ChrisF closed [Why Math Jax rendering on Chrome, but Firefox?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/141267/208359).

> This question needs details or clarity.

What "details or clarity" you need?

Answer (score 2):

Your question should really have been asked on [Maths meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com) as it concerns that site. While we are here to help  you with questions about websites, questions about other sites on the Stack Exchange network are effectively off topic as we have dedicated sites (the meta sites) for each main site.

Rather than migrate it there though it's probably best if you check to see if it's already been asked there before reposting.